# Conversão de imagem do banco para utilizar em um background

Tags: c#, imagem, kinect

estou usando o seguinte codigo para colocar botões com cada nome de categoria, porem não estou conseguindo(nao estou sabendo pesquisar) converter  para imagem o background, só me da opção de tostring.

```
        {
            ctx.DefaultContainerName = "kinectEntities";

            Console.WriteLine("View criada.. parametro = " + id);

            //cria a query geral.. "select * from produtos"
            ObjectSet<produtos> query = ctx.CreateObjectSet<produtos>();

            //cria a query com o where "select * from produtos where id_categoria = ?"
            var query2 = query.Where("it.id_categorias = @categoria");

            //adiciona o parametro na query2 select * from produtos where id_categoria = 7"
            query2.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("categoria", id));

            foreach (produtos r in query2)
            {
                //percorrendo registros da base
                var button = new KinectTileButton { Label = (r.valor).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), Tag = r.id,
                --->Background = r.imagem.ToString()<----};
                button.Click += KinectTileButtonClick;
                this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**- Para imagens salvas no banco como Base64 -**

Acredito que a imagem tenha sido salva como array de bytes (formato do dado).

Então, faça assim:

Coloque este método em alguma classe helper ou dentro do seu code-behind ou em algum lugar que você possa acessar facilmente.

```
public static ImageBrush GetBrushFromImage(byte[] imageData)
{
   ImageBrush brush;
   BitmapImage bi;
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageData))
   {
       brush = new ImageBrush();

       bi = new BitmapImage();
       bi.BeginInit();
       bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
       bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
       bi.StreamSource = ms;
       bi.EndInit();
   }

   brush.ImageSource = bi;
   return brush;
}
```

Depois chame ele assim:

```
foreach (produtos r in query2)
{
   //percorrendo registros da base
   var button = new KinectTileButton { Label = (r.valor).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), Tag = r.id, 
   Background = GetBrushFromImage(Convert.FromBase64String(r.Image))};
   button.Click += KinectTileButtonClick;
   this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
}
```

**- Para imagens salva como URI (caminho para o recurso) -**

```
public static ImageBrush GetBrushFromImageUri(string uri)
{
   return new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)));
}
```

Depois chame assim:

```
foreach (produtos r in query2)
{
   //percorrendo registros da base
   var button = new KinectTileButton { Label = (r.valor).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), Tag = r.id, 
   Background = GetBrushFromImageUri(r.Image)};
   button.Click += KinectTileButtonClick;
   this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
}
```

Comment: a imagem foi salva como string na base, pega só o caminho no servidor.

Comment: Ok, então essa string quer dizer que ela foi convertida para um array de bytes, correto? Se sim, a solução que coloquei funciona.

Comment: preciso pegar a string e exibir como imagem no background do botao, ou n sei se te entendi :S

Comment: Você precisa converter esta string para um objeto do tipo `Image`, que é o tipo que o Background aceita. Pense apenas como uma conversão de tipo. Teste o código e veja se funciona.

Comment: Fiz uma edição com um exemplo do seu código.

Comment: Deu um erro :/Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' E:\Usuario\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Clean\Vitrine\Views\HomeScreenView.xaml.cs 39 34 Vitrine

Comment: Alterei a resposta, dê uma olhada

Comment: Nenhum componente de geração de imagens adequado para concluir esta operação foi encontrado. :/ @MurariAlex

Comment: Você está usando WPF, corrreto? Me mostre o codigo que salva a imagem no banco, confirme se ela está sendo salva no formato array de bytes.

Comment: Schema::create('produtos',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('descricao');
            $table->decimal('valor',10,2);
            $table->integer('id_categorias')->unsigned();
            $table->string('imagem')->nullable(); salva como string
            $table->timestamps();

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Tente assim `Background = GetBrushFromImage(Convert.FromBase64String(r.Image))};`

Comment: Outro erro :/ to quase desistindo :/

A entrada não é uma cadeia de caracteres de Base 64 válida, pois contém um caractere que não é de base 64, mais de dois caracteres de preenchimento ou um caractere ilegal entre os caracteres de preenchimento.

Comment: Pesquisa e descobre em que formato a imagem tá no banco. Olha essa string no banco e me diz se esa string é uma base64, é uma URI, o que ela é.

Comment: no banco eu salvo apenas o caminho da imagem no meu servidor, por exemplo public/Vj3A97uCxNrjUdVToluMO1YIl67Br0UnG3XIeNsT.jpg

||| no banco é varchar(191)  utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Ah, agora tudo faz sentido, você guarda a URI da imagem. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Pronto, veja a alteração no final

Comment: Não foi possível localizar uma parte do caminho. Porem no erro mostra o caminho correto da imagem

Comment: No seu código, você vai precisar ajustar o caminho para que fique o caminho completo até o diretório onde está a imagem. Ex.: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + uri` no método GetBrushFromImageUri. A resposta está certa, só falta você ajustar para que ele ache o caminho correto.

Comment: tentei fazer assim para pegar meu diretorio.
public static ImageBrush GetBrushFromImageUri(string uri)
        {
            var imageFolder = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
                "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.30-2\apache2\htdocs\mvc\public\images");
            var firstFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(imageFolder, "*.jpg")
            .FirstOrDefault();
            return new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageFolder,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)));
        }

Comment: No debug, coloque um break point na linha onde ele monta o nome do caminho e veja se está correto. Se não estiver, vá ajustando... agora falta pouco até funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido [@MurariAlex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4343335/murarialex), muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Segue o código que utilizei para solucionar o meu problema:

```
public static ImageBrush GetBrushFromImageUri(string uri)
{
    string filePathRelativeToAssembly = Path.Combine(
        @"C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.30-2\apache2\htdocs\mvc\public",
        uri
    );

    string normalizedPath = Path.GetFullPath(filePathRelativeToAssembly);

    return new ImageBrush(
        new BitmapImage(
            new Uri(normalizedPath,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        )
    );
}
```